# Unable to run any Bare ReactNative project on my device, but expo projects run smoothly

Tags: javascript, react-native, gradle

I am Unable to run any bare react-native project on my AVD as well as on real Android device through USB Debugging.
[1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzdu7.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/988QX.png

These are images of error I received.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look on your android/build.gradle and run the proper variant like this:

react-native run-android --variant [productFlavorName][debug or release]

Example:

productFlavors {
devRunner {
dimension 'remote'
}
prodRunner {
dimension 'remote'
}
}

react-native run-android --variant devRunnerDebug

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).